# How to execute a vba procedure in your current workbook against another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template workbook (Temp_TS) that I use to create new files (based on another template) and want to then run vba code contained in Temp_TS against the new file. As all of the VBA is contained in Temp_TS, how do I specify that this should be executed against the new file I have created?

An example of one of the procedures that I will run against the new file is shown below:

```
Sub DelSheets(Optional p_sheet_to_keep1 As String = "xxx", _
              Optional p_sheet_to_keep2 As String = "yyy", _
              Optional p_sheet_to_keep3 As String = "zzz")
On Error GoTo DelSheets_err
    ' e.g. call gen.DelSheets("Parameters", "Chris Prosser")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep1) And _
           LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep2) And _
           LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep3) Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

DelSheets_exit:
    Exit Sub

DelSheets_err:
    Debug.Print "Error: ", Err.Number, vbCrLf, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

To execute this against the current workbook I would just do something like:

```
gen.DelSheets("Parameters", "Chris Prosser")
```

How would I specify that I want this to execute against the new workbook and not the current workbook?

**EDIT**

In case it helps anyone here is the method used to create the new sheet:

```
strCommand = "cp """ & oldFileName & """ """ & newFileName & """"
Shell strCommand, 1
```

This part works fine, the file is created but not opened yet.

Comment: Pass the workbook as a parameter to the sub

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Can you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: Chris:  See mehow's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `DelSheet` sub to accept a workbook as parameter (send it `byRef`)

Then add `wb.Worksheets` in your delSheet

Now you could call it from the `Main` sub like this

```
Sub Main()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\file1234.xlsm")

    DelSheets (wb)

    wb.Save
    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub


Sub DelSheets(ByRef wb As Workbook, Optional p_sheet_to_keep1 As String = "xxx", _
              Optional p_sheet_to_keep2 As String = "yyy", _
              Optional p_sheet_to_keep3 As String = "zzz")
On Error GoTo DelSheets_err
    ' e.g. call gen.DelSheets("Parameters", "Chris Prosser")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep1) And _
           LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep2) And _
           LCase(ws.Name) <> LCase(p_sheet_to_keep3) Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

DelSheets_exit:
    Exit Sub

DelSheets_err:
    Debug.Print "Error: ", Err.Number, vbCrLf, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```