# Execute VBA procedure from current workbook to other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, procedure

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590959/how-to-execute-a-vba-procedure-in-your-current-workbook-against-another-workbook) but something is still wrong and when reading my sub, i have a vba 438 error.

```
Sub theTestSub(ByRef targetWorkbook As Workbook)

    MsgBox "Delightful joy."

End Sub


Sub OpenFileAndWorkOnIt()

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook= Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\somePathThatWorks\...\.xlsm")
    
    theTestSub (targetWorkbook) '"vba error 438 object doesn't support this property or method"
        
End Sub
```

There are two things that I suspect being the cause of my problem :

- Sheets on my two workbooks having the same name (the workbooks have diffrents names)
- Missing references.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

When calling a procedure, we must not have the target within parenthesis !

```
theTestSub (targetWorkbook) '<-- Not working
theTestSub targetWorkbook '<-- Good !
```